# COVID-19 Mix-and-match (AstraZeneca & BioNTech/Pfizer): Am I considered vaccinated for travel in Europe?

Tags: covid-19

I received a first dose of AstraZeneca, and a second dose of BioNTech/Pfizer within six weeks. I am wondering if I would be considered fully vaccinated in the EU given that I received this "mix-and-match" vaccination?

---

*More context*:  I am an EU-Citizen with permanent residency in a non-EU country, where I live. This country is on the EU "green list". I will be travelling from here through a connecting EU country to another EU country, of which I am a citizen. I understand that coming from a "green list" country, I can either present proof of being fully vaccinated, or a negative PCR test upon arrival. I know that AstraZeneca and BioNTech/Pfizer, individually, are recognised, but I have not found clear information about their combination.

Comment: Since June 2021 **mix-and-match** has become common place in many countries in Europe and Germany definitely issues **EU Digital COVID Certificate**s in such a situation.

Comment: There are unfortunately no EU wide rules for which vaccinations or combinations thereof are accepted. It is always up to the acceptor and not the issuer of the vaccination certificate to decide if you are considered fully vaccinated or not. The EU is urging their memeber states to accept combinations of vaccines administrated as part of the official vaccination program in other member states, but to be sure if your combination is accepted, you have to look into the details in the actual countries you are visiting or transiting. Giving an answer for the entire EU is too broad.

Comment: Lots of AZ+Pfizer in Spain, we issue DCCs without any problem. Time between doses is relevant, if they are too close (it depends on the first shot) the second might be invalidated. And the DCC would only show that you have a complete series (2/2) and that the last one was Pfizer at the date of the second shot, without showing that the first one was AZ.

Answer (score 4):

> COVID-19 Mix-and-match (AstraZeneca & BioNTech/Pfizer): Am I considered vaccinated for travel in Europe?

Yes for France.

[Source](https://montreal.consulfrance.org/Partir-en-France-cet-ete-Recapitulatif):

> A ce stade, les autorités françaises acceptent également les combinaisons de vaccins suivantes : AstraZeneca/Pfizer Comirnaty et AstraZeneca/Moderna.

NB:

1. Policies around COVID-19 keep changing, so better check with consulates and airlines for the latest updates.
2. Each EU country has its own policy regarding the required vaccination, if any.

Answer (score 3):

I had hoped that at least for EU countries, there would be a general EMA guidance, but it appears this is not necessarily the case. So creating a wiki in case people wish to add details for particular countries as it can be a headache to plan travel (e.g., connecting flights). Of course it is important to double-check an authoritative source as information may become quickly out-of-date, and other restrictions may apply (this only relates to who is considered "vaccinated"):

- France (2021-10-18): [A ce stade, les autorités françaises acceptent également les combinaisons de vaccins suivantes : AstraZeneca/Pfizer Comirnaty et AstraZeneca/Moderna.](https://montreal.consulfrance.org/Partir-en-France-cet-ete-Recapitulatif) (From @FranckDernoncourt's answer: AstraZeneca/BioNTech-Pfizer or AstraZeneca/Moderna appear to be accepted).
- Germany (2021-10-18): [Defers to the Paul Ehrlich Institute](https://www.pei.de/DE/newsroom/dossier/coronavirus/coronavirus-inhalt.html?nn=169730&cms_pos=3), which accepts [2 doses of BioNtech-Pfizer, 2 doses of Moderna, 2 doses of Oxford-AstraZeneca, 1 dose of Jansen, or the following combinations: AstraZeneca then BioNtech-Pfizer, or AstraZeneca then Moderna, or Moderna then BioNtech-Pfizer, or BioNtech-Pfizer then Moderna](https://www.pei.de/DE/newsroom/dossier/coronavirus/coronavirus-inhalt.html?nn=169730&cms_pos=3).
- Ireland (2021-10-18): [Lists the explicit vaccination doses that are accepted (2 doses of BioNtech-Pfizer, 2 doses of Moderna, 2 doses of Oxford-AstraZeneca, 1 dose of Jansen) but does not include mention of any combination of vaccines.](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/77952-government-advice-on-international-travel/#travelling-to-ireland)
- The Netherlands (2021-10-18): [Accepts a much wider range of vaccines, including Covishield, Sinopharm, Sinovac, but does not discuss combinations.](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/requirements-for-proof-of-vaccination)
- Spain (2021-10-18): [Accepts any vaccine approved for marketing by the EMA and the WHO and mentions that the complete vaccination schedule must be available.](https://www.spth.gob.es/faq?tab=2) The EMA-accepted vaccines at this time [include AstraZeneca, BioNTech-Pfizer, Jansen, Moderna](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/human-regulatory/overview/public-health-threats/coronavirus-disease-covid-19/treatments-vaccines/vaccines-covid-19/covid-19-vaccines-authorised#safety-updates-for-authorised-covid-19-vaccines-section). The WHO has accepted [a much broader range of vaccines for Emergency Use](https://extranet.who.int/pqweb/sites/default/files/documents/Status_COVID_VAX_29Sept2021_0.pdf), but the Spanish page indicates that it is approved by the EMA *and* WHO (not clear if it's really intended as a conjunction or a disjunction).

(Feel free to extend with further details for other countries.)